# Capturing conditions in scenarios

Tags: gherkin, cucumberjs

If I have conditions for a successful scenario, I can write it as `Given, And, And... Then button is enabled.`, but how would I write the negative scenario of `If either x,y, or z aren't set, the button remains disabled`.

Here's an example of the positive scenario:

```
Scenario: Enable the Add to Favorites button
When the consumer is viewing an item
And the consumer selects an item
And the consumer selects a size
And the consumer selects a quantity
Then the Add to Favorites button becomes enabled
```

Can (or should) that be accomplished in one scenario? Since all successful "button enable" scenarios require these 3 elements, would I add them to a `Before()` hook?

Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good responses! Thanks for the input. Below is the form I went with:

```
Feature: Add item to Favorites List

    As a consumer (guest or member) who is shopping on the App, I'd like the ability to favorite items that I maybe interested in.

Rule: Any consumer, guest or member, can favorite an item after selecting pre-requisites (size/quantity/shipping)

Scenario: Favorite an item - member
Given I have logged in
And I have searched the product inventory
When I choose a desired item with specified pre-requisites
Then the app should allow me to add it to my member favorites list

Scenario: Favorite an item - guest
Given I have not logged in
And I have searched the product inventory
When I choose a desired item with specified pre-requisites
Then the app should allow me to add it to my guest favorites list
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Scenario: Do not enable the Add to Favorites button without a selected item
When the consumer is viewing an item
And the consumer selects a size
And the consumer selects a quantity
Then the Add to Favorites button does not become enabled

Scenario: Do not enable the Add to Favorites button without a selected size
When the consumer is viewing an item
And the consumer selects an item
And the consumer selects a quantity
Then the Add to Favorites button does not become enabled

Scenario: Do not enable the Add to Favorites button without a selected quantity
When the consumer is viewing an item
And the consumer selects an item
And the consumer selects a size
Then the Add to Favorites button does not become enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

As the scenario outline approach is best to test the multiple inputs and output. So considering the same scenario as follows:

```
    Scenario Outline: Verify the "Add to Favorites" button state
        When the consumer is viewing an item
        And the item is "<itemCondition>"
        And the item size is "<sizeCondition>"
        And the item quantity is "<quantityCondition>"
        Then the "Add to Favorites" button becomes "<buttonState>"
        Examples: Conditions
            | itemCondition | sizeCondition | quantityCondition | buttonState|
            | Selected      | Selected      | Selected          | enabled    |
            | Not Selected  | Not Selected  | Not Selected      | disabled   |
            | Selected      | Not Selected  | Not Selected      | disabled   |
            | Selected      | Selected      | Not Selected      | disabled  |
```